# Creating a rolling flat log file using Enterprise library

Tags: asp.net, logging, enterprise-library

In my web application I am trying to create a log file for logging errors and exceptions, but when I run my application, log file is not getting created in my solution folder or in bin folder.

I used the following code. Please help me I am stuck up with this problem, thank you in advance.

**namespaces used**

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;

using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration;
```

**.cs file**

```
        public int GetdeskKMasterRecordsCount(string CircleId, string StoreId)
        {
            try
            {
               throw new Exception("this is normal exception");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                BindLog(ex);
                return 0;
            }
        }


        public static void BindLog(Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex == null) return;
            Logger.Write(LogInformation(1, DateTime.Now, ex.Message, " "));

        }

        public static LogEntry LogInformation(int eventId, DateTime timeStamp, string message, string documentName)
        {
            LogEntry logEntryObject = new LogEntry();
            logEntryObject.EventId = eventId;
            logEntryObject.Title = documentName;
            logEntryObject.TimeStamp = timeStamp;
            logEntryObject.MachineName = System.Environment.MachineName;
            logEntryObject.Message = message;
            logEntryObject.Categories.Add("Exception");

            return logEntryObject;
        }
```

**Web Config file**

```
<configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <section name="recordingWindowGroup" type="Vodafone.DMS.BAL.WindowConfigurationHandler, Vodafone.DMS.BAL"/>
    <section name="defaultParamGroup" type="Vodafone.DMS.BAL.DefaultParamConfiguration, Vodafone.DMS.BAL"/>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener"
           type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           fileName="Vodafone.DMS.log.exclude" footer="---------------------------" formatter="Text Formatter" header="---------------------------" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment"
           rollSizeKB="10" timeStampPattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" maxArchivedFiles="7" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp, Callstack" filter="All"/>
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add template="Timestamp: {timestamp}&#xA;Message: {message}&#xA;Category: {category}&#xA;Priority: {priority}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}&#xA;Severity: {severity}&#xA;Title:{title}&#xA;Machine: {machine}&#xA;Application Domain: {appDomain}&#xA;Process Id: {processId}&#xA;Process Name: {processName}&#xA;Win32 Thread Id: {win32ThreadId}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}&#xA;"
           type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="Text Formatter"/>
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener"/>
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener"/>
        </listeners>
      </allEvents>
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener"/>
        </listeners>
      </notProcessed>
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener"/>
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 5):

For enterprise library `version 5.0 and above`, Microsoft has released an enterprise library configuration [tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/029292f0-6e66-424f-8381-3454c8222f9a) that allows you to change the configurations visually in the `configuration file`. You can also install this tool from NuGet and that can be accessed from inside the visual studio **`Tools >> Library Package Manager >> Manage NuGet Packages for solution`** and add the appropriate **`EntLib Application Block`**. You can find guide from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664633%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx).

Using that tool I have generated a configuration file which is as follows:

**Place this in Web.Config or App.Config file**

```
  <loggingConfiguration name="loggingConfiguration" tracingEnabled="true"
    defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        fileName="RollingFlatFile.log"
        footer="---------------------------" formatter="Text Formatter"
        header="---------------------------" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment"
        rollInterval="Week" rollSizeKB="20000" timeStampPattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
        maxArchivedFiles="7" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId, Callstack"
        filter="All" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        template="Timestamp: {timestamp}&#xA;Message: {message}&#xA;Category: {category}&#xA;Priority: {priority}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}&#xA;Severity: {severity}&#xA;Title:{title}&#xA;Machine: {machine}&#xA;Application Domain: {appDomain}&#xA;Process Id: {processId}&#xA;Process Name: {processName}&#xA;Win32 Thread Id: {win32ThreadId}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}&#xA;"
        name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </allEvents>
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </notProcessed>
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
```

I would recommend that instead of generating the log file inside the bin directory of the application you should specify a physical location by changing the value of the **`fileName="RollingFlatFile.log"`** to something like **`fileName="c:\logs\RollingFlatFile.log"`**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a category on your LogEntry to match a category source in your configuration file ('General' in the configuration you posted). I would also suggest looking at the Exception Handling Application Block if you are planning to log exceptions, instead of writing the code to handle creating a LogEntry yourself.

Answer (score -2):

```
IConfigurationSource configurationSource = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();
LogWriterFactory logWriterFactory = new LogWriterFactory(configurationSource);
Logger.SetLogWriter(logWriterFactory.Create(), false);
Logger.Write("btnStartProcess_Click");
Logger.Reset();
```

Comment: Generally you want to post more than a code dump. Explain why this'll work/etc. You'll help both the OP and future readers by doing so.